# Nav with 1 column on mobile, 2 columns on mid-size, single line centered on large screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigationbar

I'm trying to create a text-only footer-nav which appears as a single column (centered) on mobile devices, two columns with centered text on mid-size devices, and a single line centered on desktops.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid container-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="nav nav-footer left">
            <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link C with longer name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link E</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
         <ul class="nav nav-footer right">
            <li><a href="#">Link F</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link G</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link H</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK I</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-footer {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;   
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.container-footer a {
    color: #464646;  
}
.nav-footer {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.nav-footer li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;   
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .nav-footer li {
        width: auto;
        display: block;       
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
      .nav-footer li {
        width: auto;
        display: inline-block;       
    }
    .left {
      text-align: right;
    }
   .right {
      text-align: left;
    }
}
```

This is as close as I've been able to get: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbbyKK

In the pen, it all works as I'd like it to except for the single-line display on larger screens (above 992px).  The main problem is that because there are more items in the left column than the right, the entire menu skews to the left of the screen.

There's probably an obvious way to do this that I'm just not seeing because I've stared at this for too long now so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things quite a bit. No need for that many wrapper divs, or for breaking the list of links in 2. Here I use [multi column layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol-1/) to get two balanced columns at the medium size. For the larger size, I just undo it, and your inline-block technique works fine now that the list isn't split in halfs anymore.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container-fluid container-footer">
      <ul class="nav nav-footer">
        <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link C with longer name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link H</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK I</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-footer {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.container-footer a {
  color: #464646;
}
.nav-footer {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.nav-footer li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-footer li {
    width: auto;
  }
  .nav-footer {
    -ms-columns:2; -moz-columns:2; -webkit-columns:2; columns:2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .nav-footer {
    -ms-columns:auto; -moz-columns:auto; -webkit-columns:auto; columns:auto;
  }
  .nav-footer li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVVXWz